# Should i user windows roles in session?

Tags: c#, .net, security, session

this might be very silly question but was wondering is there any advantage to store user windows roles in session. Basically in our mvc project before we render the view we check  if user has access to see the views based on user roles. I am looking at security point of view for storing them in session vs performance

```
   public class WindowsRoleProvider : IRoleProvider
   {
       public List<string> GetWindowsRolesForUser(string userName)
       {
          var windowsProvider = new WindowsTokenRoleProvider();
          var adsRoles = windowsProvider.GetRolesForUser(userName);
          return new List<string>(adsRoles);
       }
    }
    public  List<string> GetUserRoles(string userName)
    {
        var userRoles = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            var windowsRoles = _roleProvider.GetWindowsRolesForUser(userName);
            adsRoles = windowsRoles.ConvertAll(d => d.ToLowerInvariant());
            var catAuthorizationRoles = _configurationManager.GetSection("catroles");
            if (catAuthorizationRoles != null)
            {
                for (var role = 0; role < catAuthorizationRoles.Count; role++)
                {
                    if (windowsRoles.Any(item =>catAuthorizationRoles[role].ToLower().ToLower().Split(';').Any(s => item.Trim().Equals(s.Trim()))))
                    {
                        userRoles.Add(catAuthorizationRoles.GetKey(role));
                    }
                }
            }
            userRoles = userRoles.ConvertAll(d => d.ToLower());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error("Exception:" + ex.Message + "\r\nInner Exception:" +
                         (ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.Message : string.Empty) + "\r\n" +
                         ex.StackTrace);
        }

        return userRoles;
    }
```

Comment: What happens if a user's session is still active while you revoke his permissions? Because they're cached in session-state (and provided he keeps his session alive) then he could continue to have access when you don't want him to.

Comment: There is really no good concrete answer - there are valid reasons for (as it likely be faster) and against (likely go stale), but you need to think what is important in your case. Note that there is likely other data in session that relies on that information too (i.e. some sort of cached responses) that you need to carefully review from security point of view too.